# How to dragscroll X and Y?

Tags: jquery, plugins, draggable, scrollable

I need something like this:

http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html

I have an area that should be "dragscrollable" in every direction.

I've tried a lot of plugins, but every one has some bugs (mostly cannot scroll with mousewheel or scrollbars are buggy).

I would like to test the dragscrollable plugin, but the jquery plugin page is "under construction", so I cannot download it with documentation etc.
Does anyone how to get this plugin or another good method do dragscroll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a direct link to the plugin.

http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollsync.js 
http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/dragscrollable.js 

the documentation is already included there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another dragscroll library (that I've written):

Utterscroll, http://www.debiki.com/dev/utterscroll

It differs from other libraries in that it 1) understands if you intend to select text, rather than scrolling, and 2) it needs no, or almost no, configuration.